# Is there any commentary available on Kutashlokas (VyasRahsya) of Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata

Ganesha agreed to scribe Mahabharata only if Vyasa speak shlokas in continuation. But, Vyasa needed time to think shlokas so he put one condition that Ganesha would write shloka only after understanding them. Vyasa spoke very difficult some shlokas which took much time of Ganesha to understand and Vyasa could think other sholkas meanwhile. Is there any commentary available on these shlokas known as Kutashlokas or VyasaRahsya of Mahabharata?

Comment: Did you mean 800 or 8000?

Comment: I think this number varies, 800 or 8000 or 8800 @sv.